# (C言語)全ての数値が被らなくなるまで乱数を生成して配列に格納する方法

Tags: c

下記のコード（mainやincludeの部分は省略してます）で実行するとprintfが出力されず、プログラムも最後まで動かなくて止まりません。
コンパイルでは成功してて警告やエラーも出てません。
ずっと考えて少しずつ修正を加えたり試してるのですが、全然作れそうにないです。
どうすればタイトルのような機能を作れますか？

コード：

```
int len = 63;
int place[len];
struct timeval tv;

for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    srand((unsigned int)tv.tv_sec * ((unsigned int)tv.tv_usec + 1));
    place[i] = rand() % 62;
}

int f=0;
for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    while(1) {
        f=0;
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
            if(place[i] == place[j]) f=1;
        }
        if(f==1) {
            gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
            srand((unsigned int)tv.tv_sec * ((unsigned int)tv.tv_usec + 1));
            place[i] = rand() % 62;
        } else {
            printf("%d ", place[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

本題から外れるから部分(`srand()` の使い方がおかしいとか)は置いておくとして、単純に `place` が要素数 63 個の配列なのに

```
place[i] = rand() % 62;
```

で取りうる値が 0 ~ 61 の 62 通りしかないので、`while(1)` から抜けることはありえません。`rand()` のところは２箇所とも

```
place[i] = rand() % len;
```

とすればいいと思います。

Comment: lenにしてみたところ、whileから抜けて動きました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 5):

単に `0` から `len-1` までの数字の順序をランダムに並べ替えたいということなら、もっと効率よく書くことができると思います。

```
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            place[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            int j = i + (rand() % (len - i));
            // swap(place[i], place[j]);
            int tmp = place[i];
            place[i] = place[j];
            place[j] = tmp;
    }
```

参考: [フィッシャー - イェーツのシャッフル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC_-_%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%84%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB)

Answer (score 2):

@TatzSekine さんは問題の所在を言及していました。こちらの意見も察してほしい。

乱数を1つずつ生成して、重複しないまで走らせて、恐らく、多くの時間がかかります。（`len = 10000` と試したら、２秒ぐらいかかってしまいました）

こちらの考えは、被らない配列を作って、そして数字をシャッフルすることです。すなわち

```
int len = 63;
int mod = len;
int place[len];
struct timeval tv;

gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
// 最初に一度 srand 初期化すれば良いです
srand((unsigned int)tv.tv_sec * ((unsigned int)tv.tv_usec + 1));

for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    place[i] = i;
}

int x, y, j, tmp;
// 何回交換して十分にランダムになれますか、試してみたら、len と同じと良い
int swap_times = len;
for (j = 0; j < swap_times; ++j) {
    x = rand() % len;
    y = rand() % len;
    tmp = place[x];
    place[x] = place[y];
    place[y] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: `0～指定数`の順番を変えたいだけなら、この方法がベストかと思いますね。質問者の意図が「"0～指定数"の中から重複しないように指定数未満の数を取得する」なら別ですが……

Comment: @Myaku その場合でもこの手法で良い(テーブル先頭から指定個数の数を取り出せば題意に合致する）でしょうね。